# JPanel: automatically paint at creation?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

This must be rather trivial and straight forward, but I cannot figure it out.

This is what my JPanel looks like, it is added to a JFrame:

```
private class RadarPanel extends JPanel {       
        public RadarPanel() {
            super();
            this.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            //painting logic here

            //repaint in 500 ms
            this.repaint(500);
        }
    }
```

Now, when I resize the JFrame this JPanel starts getting redrawn all the time. However, when I do not resize the JFrame the JPanel's paintComponent method does not seem to get called, even though I call repaint in the constructor.

Any advice? Thanks.

UPDATE:

more complete code (everything except drawing logic):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayerRadar extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 230324190;

    //settings
    private static final int windowWidth = 300;
    private static final int windowHeight = 300;
    private static final int maxDistance = 250;

    //components
    private PlayerRadar radarWindow;
    private JPanel radarPanel;

    public PlayerRadar(String title) {
        super(title);

        //set reference
        radarWindow = this;

        //create radar window
        Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
        this.setBounds(screenSize.width - windowWidth, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                radarWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        this.setVisible(true);

        //create a JPanel for drawing
        radarPanel = new RadarPanel();
        radarPanel.setBounds(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        radarPanel.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));

        //add to frame
        this.getContentPane().add(radarPanel);
    }

    private class RadarPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 230324191;
        private static final int repaintInterval = 500;

        public RadarPanel() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        //draw player oval (center of the frame)
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE); //blue
        int ovalWidth = (int) Math.round(this.getWidth() / 30);
        int ovalHeight = (int) Math.round(this.getHeight() / 30);
        int playerLocalX = (int) Math.round(this.getWidth() / 2);
        int playerLocalY = (int) Math.round(this.getHeight() / 2);
        int ovalX = playerLocalX - ovalWidth / 2;
        int ovalY = playerLocalY - ovalHeight / 2;
        g.fillOval(ovalX, ovalY, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); //black
        g.drawOval(ovalX, ovalY, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);

        //get info of the player itself
        PlayerInfo thisPlayer = GameUtil.getPlayerInfo();
        float playerPosZ = thisPlayer.position[0];
        float playerPosX = thisPlayer.position[2];
        //float playerRotRad = thisPlayer.rotation;

        //set rectangle specs
        int rectWidth = this.getWidth() / 40;
        int rectHeight = this.getWidth() / 40;

        //only continue if we have information about our player
        if (thisPlayer != null) {
            //get nearby players
            ArrayList<PlayerInfo> playersInfo = GameUtil.getNearbyPlayers();

            //for each other player, draw a rectangle
            for (PlayerInfo playerInfo : playersInfo) {                 
                //get data
                float posZ = playerInfo.position[0];
                float posX = playerInfo.position[2];
                //float rotRad = playerInfo.rotation;

                //calculate relative x and y
                int rectX = playerLocalX + Math.round((posX - playerPosX) / maxDistance * this.getWidth() / 2) - rectWidth / 2;
                int rectY = playerLocalY + ovalHeight / 2 + Math.round((playerPosZ - posZ) / maxDistance * this.getHeight() / 2)  - rectHeight / 2;

                //draw rectangle
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
        }

        //repaint soon
        this.repaint(repaintInterval);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where correct the first time. Custom painting is done in the paintComponent() method, NOT the paint() method.

You should NEVER invoke repaint() from within the paintComponent() method, since that will result in an infinite loop.

If you want to animate the painting, then you should be using a Swing Timer to schedule the animation.

You should not be using use setSize(). That is the job of the layout manager. Instead you can override the getPreferredSize() method of the panel (or use setPreferredSize()) and then you can pack() the frame, instead of setting its size.

The panel should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible otherwise it has a size of (0, 0) which means there is nothing to paint.

Comment: Can you please explain or point to something that would describe why the painting should be done in painComponent() and not paint() and what is the big difference, I probably done it wrong for a long time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @m0s, overriding paint is done when using AWT. However, in Swing you override paintComponent. Here is a link to the Swing tutorial on Custom Painting: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: @camickr if I want the painting job to go on indefinitely, is it not alright to use repaint inside paintComponent with a specified delay?

Comment: Also, I implemented your suggestions (removed setSize, use setPreferredSize and pack and now set the frame visible after the pannel is added), unfortunately I still have to resize the window once to get the jpanel to paint itself.

Comment: Update: it does update now that I use a swing timer. Not sure why, but it works. Probably the first time fails for some reason and then the timer makes sure it does hit the next one.

Comment: Swing will repaint the component as necessary. The only reason you need to invoke repaint is if you change something in the component. Generally in a game context this means you move the player to a new location. You should NOT have to resize the frame to get it to paint the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It won't repaint until your form is shown and graphics is initialized. I don't think calling repaint in constructor is a good idea. It will repaint once the component is visible.

Comment: @m0s, that's what I thought as well. But when I do not add repaint in the constructor, it won't execute paintComponent either I believe. It only starts updating after I resize the window once.

Comment: Just tested. If I don't resize the JFrame, the JPanel never gets drawed. When I resize the JFrame, the JPanel gets drawed and updated every 500ms.

Comment: Is your JFrame big enough? If your JPanel has height or width 0, no painting is going to happen.

Comment: @lins314159, this is what I set for the JFrame: this.setBounds(screenSize.width - windowWidth, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); and this is what I set for the JPanel: panel.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);

Comment: What is interesting is that when I call frame.pack() after adding the jpanel the window is made very small, as if it does not recognize the size of the jpanel (even though I set it).

Comment: @Tom maybe try putting your paint logic in paint() instead of paintComponent() methods? Thats how I usually do this kind of thing and it works.

Comment: @m0s I updated my question with the full code (apart from the actual drawing logic).

Comment: @Tom I added these two lines              g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.fillOval(0, 0, 200, 200); to the paint method where the draw logic is supposed to be and it draws a black filled circle as supposed to. I'm guessing you might have problems in your drawing logic.

Comment: @m0s. I just tested it myself by replacing all my draw logic with your two lines and I algo get the expected result. In my draw logic I use Dimension size = this.getSize(); - maybe this is only set after resizing the whole thing? Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Update: while that seems likely to cause the problems, adding panel.setSize(width, height) etc. does not seem to fix my problem either.. maybe you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Tom g.fillOval(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height); again works fine, there must be something else causing problem in your drawing routine. It is hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @m0s I updated the code to the complete version. However, the only logic in there that would not make it paint is if either of my functions returns null, in which case it will still call repaint in 500ms. Also, this has nothing to do with the size of the window. Yet, a resize of the JFrame (the window) causes the paint loop to finally activate.

Comment: @Tom I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with either math :) I don't have the time to go step by step on this code, but here here is a suggestion how I would debug this: put few println statements to output players coordinates and check that everything is correct, also this way you will know what getNearbyPlayers returns.